# Billing limit for Heroku

Tags: heroku, limit, billing

I am getting started on Heroku and concerned whether it will charge me for a mistake I do. For example, filling up the database over 5MB.
So, is there a way to set billing limit to an Heroku or notification system to send a notification when I go over the price limit?

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: This is a vendor support question, not a programming question. It's off-topic here. If you have questions about billing policies, ask the company that's doing the billing. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is pretty clear about what types of questions are proper to ask here. Keeping things on-topic helps make SO a useful programming resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont think so. But heroku only bills u if you actually signed up for something, like an addon, that is non free. If you use up 5 megs of database, they would send u an email telling you that you are over the limit, and would simply stop all INSERT operations to the database.

Another thing to note is not to leave heroku console on longer than necessary, since that requires another worker and is billable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Specially about console being a worker.

Comment: No problem! Got bitten once, and don't think it was explicitly stated on the Heroku's site. But it's not their fault anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

All limits are soft limits. The new row limits imposed on the database plans if exceeded will trigger an email notification for you to take action.